# Extend a View to match its parent layout with dynamic content

Tags: android, xml, android-xml

I am working on a complex layout structure like the images below. The Blue Layout/View needs to extend as the numbers of Red layouts increases vertically like in 2nd Image. And yes the purple layout height should be wrap-content (should not matches to the parent) as per requirement. 
Problem arises when I set the BLUE layout as match-parent, it takes the height of whole screen.

[image]

After RED layout increases dynamically:

[image]

Comment: Not sure how you decided to build your layout, but having a look at this might help you : https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/index.html Basically you'd define your "red dots container" as wrap_content, and then add constraints to your "blue layout" to match "the red dots container" height

Comment: you can do this pro-grammatically

Comment: can you post your code ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Output]

Here's **drawable/circle_red** xml file

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <item>
            <shape android:shape="oval">
                <solid android:color="#f1ce2a2a" />
                <corners android:radius="2dp" />
            </shape>
        </item>

    </layer-list>
```

Main layout xml file have a look

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:baselineAligned="false"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/home"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#4f56be"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:padding="5dp">
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="vertical">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="60dp"
                    android:layout_height="60dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:background="@drawable/circle_red"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textColor="#fff"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    />
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="60dp"
                    android:layout_height="60dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:background="@drawable/circle_red"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textColor="#fff"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    />
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="60dp"
                    android:layout_height="60dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:background="@drawable/circle_red"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textColor="#fff"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    />
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="60dp"
                    android:layout_height="60dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:background="@drawable/circle_red"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textColor="#fff"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"/>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer and Yes it works like expected. I was able to solve it after an hour later I posted the question though. Due to the complexity of layout it was a minor part and I lost myself in this complex layout. It was quite simple. I finally decided to go with a simple approach just like how you did and It worked!! and yes I'll mark it accepted :)